# I need to add a dll to a nuget package without referencing it and modify the csprof file to include the dll

Tags: powershell, nuget, csproj

I have a nuget package with one dll that needs to be referenced and one dll that just needs to be included in the output of the program.

Relavent info from nuspec:

```
<references>
    <reference file="dllA.dll" />
</references>
</metadata>
<files>
    <file src="dllA.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="dllB.dll" target="content" />
</files>
```

I have been playing around with the install.ps1 file to try to modify the .csproj to add this section:

```
<Content Include="<path to dllB.dll">
  <Link>dllB.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

I don't know how to get the path to dllB and I'm having trouble modifying the .csproj during the nuget package install with powershell.